# PHP Check if var is 0 or 1 and then print accordingly

Tags: php, html, sql

Im getting an integer from my database that is either 0 or 1. With this information i want to change a string to say Esea. This is my code which isn't working:

```
<?php
$esea = '';

if (!empty($final_data['esea'])) {
    $esea = 'Esea'
}

?>
```

Then this is where i print it:

```
<p><?php echo $esea ?></p>
```

Comment: Note that `null` is not `0`; your title says `null`, your question talks about `0`. Though the `empty()` function should treat `0` and `null` both [the same](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and return true. Are you sure `$final_data['esea']` contains what you expect it contains? Did you [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) it? Can you post the output of `var_dump($final_data['esea']);` or even `var_dump($final_data);`?

Comment: You can also perform strict comparison, like this: `if($final_data['esea'] === 1) { // your code }`

Comment: post the php code which database retrieval part

Comment: If some code doesn't do what you want, the very first step is to have a look at the values you're dealing with! `var_dump($final_data)`

Comment: if ($final_data['esea']) {
    $esea = 'Esea';
}

Comment: Sorry guys it's 0 not null. I've updatet it

Comment: You better post the output from the, several times suggested by now, `var_dump()` instead of fixing your title ;-)

Comment: var_dump() is giving me NULL

Comment: Well then figure out where `$final_data` is supposed to come from!

Comment: @Tim '*var_dump() is giving me NULL*' You might want to clear that up. Did you do a literal `var_dump()` or `var_dump($final_data)` or `var_dump($final_data['esea'])`? Please add the actual statement and the actual output in your question.

Comment: I did a var_dump($final_data['esea']) which gave me null. Im sorry guys for being slow im new to PHP @Roblll

Comment: @Tim Then there's your problem. You wrote: `if (!empty(...))` which means: if **not** empty (that's what the `!` does). So your code does exactly what it's supposed to do. Now you either need to make sure `$final_data['esea']` is populated with the correct value or you need to correct your code if/else logic.

Comment: Thanks Roblll for taking the time to help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myvalue= '';

if (!empty($final_data['esea'])) {
    $myvalue= 'Foo'
} else {
    $myvalue= 'Bar'
}

echo $myvalue;
```

If the output is `Foo` then `$final_data['esea']` was one of:

> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - 0.0 (0 as a float)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (an empty array)

[See the `empty()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues).

If the output is `Bar` then `$final_data['esea']` was none of the above values.

Also see the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739852/php-check-if-var-is-0-or-1-and-then-print-accordingly/36740579#comment61062726_36739852) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739852/php-check-if-var-is-0-or-1-and-then-print-accordingly/36740579#comment61062905_36739852).

Also note that the above code can be rewritten to:

```
$myvalue= '';

if (empty($final_data['esea'])) {
    $myvalue= 'Bar'
} else {
    $myvalue= 'Foo'
}

echo $myvalue;
```

Which is *functionally* **exactly** the same. The only difference is `emtpy(...)` v.s. `!empty(...)` (and ofcourse the logic in the if/else swapped).

Comment: Thank you @Roblll ur a gentleman and a scholar!

Comment: I'd skip the initial assignment of `''`, since you're always going to overwrite it afterwards anyway...

Comment: @deceze In this example; maybe. But it's usually (not to say always) a good idea to initialize your variables. This way, when you later refactor your code (and drop the `else { ... }` part maybe) you won't be referencing an uninitialized variable. Having said that; I come from a C# background where stuff like this is not just only good practice but even *required*. I do, however, think this applies to any language. Also see [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php): '*It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a very good practice (...)*'

Comment: ... and [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) goes on with: "*Relying on the default value of an uninitialized variable is problematic in the case of including one file into another which uses the same variable name. It is also a major [security risk](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) with [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) turned on.  E_NOTICE level error is issued in case of working with uninitialized variables (...)*" etc. etc. So, I strongly suggest you initialize your variables, even in PHP.

Comment: Sure, you must initialise your variables. But in this case you're doing it twice, which is why I point out that once is enough. IMO it's not productive to try to defend against future mistakes you might introduce during a refactor, but that's just me. If I was worried about that I'd initialise it the way the OP did in the first place: default ("else") value initially, overwrite `if` some condition is true...